# php variable as a mysql column name

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to find solution for this about everywhere, but nothing Google gave seems to work for my specific case.

My table has 4 columns that I want updated that I have named 0, 1, 2, 3, conveniently as I have to loop through it to update.
Here is one instance of the column structure :

```
 column name 0 ENUM('Y','N') null=no default='N'
```

Now I want to set the value to 'Y' using this loop, but it will not accept the way I am referring to the $i variable within the query.

See below my last attempt. I also tried to cast $i as int, but that did not work either.

I appreciate your guidance on this.

```
                     /* update versions columns to Y where applicable */
        for ($i=0;$i <= $ctvid-1;$i++){
        $sql = mysql_query (
        "SELECT trim_id
        FROM versiontrim
        WHERE (
        version_id =$arr_vid[$i]
        )");
        $escapedi=mysql_real_escape_string($i);
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ))
        {
        $r=$row1['trim_id'];
        mysql_query ("UPDATE ttcomp SET '".$escapedi."' ='Y' where         trim_id=$r ");
        }
                    }
```

Comment: SQL injection attracts sould be with your codes when we use variable directly to the SQl.And Ua are using deprecated mysql

Comment: Dear Your Common Sense, you may read it more carefully before you say anything. I believe I have clearly stated my issue and in the interest of efficiency I indicated what I already tried and did not work. Your lecture is unnecessary and misplaced.

Comment: Have you tried using ` around your column names instead of `'`?

Comment: Thanks Phill, did try that with no success.

Comment: Hi again Phill. Your solution works. I had another problem downstream that was keeping me from getting the correct result. Found it now. t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):

Therefore, if you *must* name your columns in this way (and, really, you *should* find some other solution), you will need to quote them with backticks:

```sql
UPDATE ttcomp SET `0` = 'Y' WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php variable as the name of a SQL column like this.

```
UPDATE tablename SET `".$variable."`= whatever
```